# Timer does not stop at old activity

Tags: android, android-timer

I set a timer on `AccountActivity.class` to ensure that user does not press home button if not will start the countdown to logout the user or if the user locks his screen.

But now I am facing an issue because of the `onPause` method. When my user clicks on a button which invokes the `getaccounttask()` method and it will redirect my user to `AccountInformationActivity.class`, the `onPause` method is activated as well and the timer starts to countdown.

Is there any solution to prevent the `onPause` method from counting down or the timer to be cancelled on my `AccountInformationActivity.class`?

I tried to do the cancelling of timer before my intent starts but still does not work.

I have tried using handler as well but encountered the same problem, I am still trying to grasp how Android fully works, so your help or solution is deeply appreciated.

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
    }

    private class getaccounttask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... urlaccount)
      {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            //My Codes
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AccountInformationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        timer = new Timer();
        Log.i("Main", "Invoking logout timer");
        LogOutTimerTask logoutTimeTask = new LogOutTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(logoutTimeTask, 300000); //auto logout in 5 minutes
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i("Main", "cancel timer");
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private class LogOutTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //redirect user to login screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the implementation architecture you choose could be improved. I shall come to that later. First apply this quick fix to fix your architecture.

Clearly you want to start a `Timer` when you go out of `Activity` using home screen. But user can also go out of `Activity` by using `Intent` to switch to `AccountActivity`. This you can track. So keep a boolean flag like `shouldNavigate`, initially it should be `false`. when `onResume`, it should be set to `false`, but when `getcounttask` goes to `onPostExecute` it should be set to `true`. So in `onPause`, if you are going out via `getcounttask`,`shouldNavigate` is going to be `true` and if is `true`, cancel your Timer else, start your `Timer`.

Code:

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Timer timer;
    private volatile boolean shouldNavigate = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
    }

    private class getaccounttask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... urlaccount)
      {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            //My Codes
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
        shouldNavigate = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AccountInformationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (!shouldNavigate){
            timer = new Timer();
            Log.i("Main", "Invoking logout timer");
            LogOutTimerTask logoutTimeTask = new LogOutTimerTask();
            timer.schedule(logoutTimeTask, 300000); 
        }else{
            if (timer != null){
                  timer.cancel();
                  timer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        shouldNavigate = false;
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i("Main", "cancel timer");
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private class LogOutTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //redirect user to login screen
            shouldNavigate = false;
            Intent i = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Now a better approach could be keep a `Service` and a `Singleton` class.
The Singleton class would be

```
public Singleton{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private Singleton(){
        activityMap = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
         if (instance == null) instance = new Singeton();
         return instance;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Activity> activityMap;

}
```

Now each activity will have a Tag (like its name), so each activity when resumes will do

```
Singleton.getInstance().activityMap.put(tag, this);
```

and when goes to `onPause` will do

```
Singleton.getInstance().activityMap.remove(tag, this);
```

So when the service finds that size of `Singleton.getInstance().activityMap` is zero then clearly no activity is on foreground, so it starts a timer. when the timer expires check again if the count is still zero, if zero then perform your logout.

Comment: Hi, I did try handler as well but I am stuck at the same problem. For the tracking part of shouldNavigate I am still not really sure as I am still new to Android and Java, if you could provide some codes it will be awesome and a great help for me to understand

Comment: please check edit, and ofcourse fix according to your need.

Comment: OMG..Finally it worked! Thanks alot! I have been stuck on this issue for like weeks! Once again thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Make some modifications in `onPause()` and add this permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (isApplicationSentToBackground(this)) {
            // Do what you want to do on detecting Home Key being Pressed
            timer = new Timer();
            Log.i("Main", "Invoking logout timer");
            LogOutTimerTask logoutTimeTask = new LogOutTimerTask();
            timer.schedule(logoutTimeTask, 300000); //auto logout in 5 minutes
            Log.i("Main", "Invoking Home Key pressed");
        }
        super.onPause();

    }

    public boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you try this.